# Difference Between data-main and normal script loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When using RequireJS, what's the difference between including your script with

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

i.e. what does the `data-main` attribute change about loading in a script?  I've [read through the docs on this](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main), and the different isn't entirely clear to me.

> You will typically use a data-main script to set configuration options and then load the first application module. Note: the script tag require.js generates for your data-main module includes the async attribute. This means that you cannot assume that the load and execution of your data-main script will finish prior to other scripts referenced later in the same page.

The documentation mentions that you'll *typically use a data-main script to set configuration options and load the first application module* — but can't you also do that via a plain old `script` tag?  Is there a benefit to doing configuration loading the application module with a `data-main` attribute?

Is the only different with `data-main` the asynchronous loading?  Or is there something more?

Comment: Yeah the documentation isn't great,  "You would typically use a ..."  but then they don't explain why.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`data-main` is just another way to perform the initial `require` call of your application. To illustrate... this:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

is equivalent to this:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>require(["scripts/main"])</script>
```

**The two forms are both asynchronous.** This is really all there is to it. Considerations about how many entry points you have or where the RequireJS configuration is going to be located are completely orthogonal to the use of `data-main`. To put it differently, these considerations play a role in your use of `data-main` to the exact same extent that they play a role in your use of `require(["scripts/main"])`.

The part of the documentation you quoted is just obscuring things by mentioning that the script loaded with `data-main` creates a `script` element in the `head` element with the `async` attribute set, because *this is not different from loading any script through RequireJS*. Every single script loaded by RequireJS will have a `script` element created for it, in the `head`, and have the `async` attribute set.

It is common to use `data-main` for applications that have only a single entry point, and to put RequireJS' configuration in the module specified in `data-main`, but it is not required by any means. For instance, this is a perfectly valid use:

```
<script>
    require = {
        // RequireJS config here...
    };
</script>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["foo"], function (foo) {
        foo.something();
    });
</script>
```

The configuration is given to RequireJS by setting `require` in the global space before loading RequireJS. (If `require` is defined before RequireJS is loaded, it will take `require`'s value as its configuration.) Besides kicking off the application by loading `scripts/main`, this code also loads `foo` and calls a method on it: two entry points.

Comment: Thanks @Louis -- exactly the clarification I wanted!

Answer (score 5):

`data-main` is for when you want to have a **single entry point** to your application. That single script line will load RequireJS along with `scripts/main.js` and kick off your app.

The result of

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

is that `<script async src="scripts/main.js"></script>` is appended to the document at runtime; this is the script that will contain your `require.config()` block and pull in your first application script. If you don't specify a `data-main`, then you're only loading Require and none of your app scripts, unless you explicitly load a config file and the first module.

What do you think Require will load if you don't tell it to load anything?

---

If you do *not* use `data-main`, you must provide an entry point *after* loading Require (this is how I have always done it, for no good reason other than that's how I learned it.) Read about the [configuration options](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) to see how you would do this.

I use [this pattern](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module#2) in development:

```
<script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script>
  // same as data-main
  require.config({baseUrl : 'js'});
  require(['js/main']);
</script>
```

As a single entry point, the contents of `config.js` and the subsequent `require(['js/main'])` call would be in whichever script is referenced as `data-main`.

---

If you use the static optimizer to build a production bundle, none of this matters because you just load the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

data-main is the script that require.js will process. As the documentation says, it is common to set configuration options in that script. But there are other ways to do that. In many cases it is the easiest and most effective place. But not always.

The script pointed to by data-main will also list the dependencies for the code that the file defines. The dependencies are where the meat is. It is typical, though not required, to have this first module load and execute what is ultimately the actual application.

**Addendum in response to the comment:**

There are some concepts you need to be aware of that will help make sense of this approach.

First is that there isn't a single (or a couple, or even a few) script(s). This type of loader is designed to handle lots and lots of very small scripts. Each with a very specific and often (preferably) single purpose. Call these scripts modules (or units).

Any given module might depend on any number of other modules in order to function. The AMD pattern allows the dependencies for each module to be listed within that module's definition.

RequireJS will sort out who needs what and in what order and not let scripts execute until all the modules they depend on are loaded and ready.

So this is not at all like putting a script link (or multiple links) in a page as we all grew up doing. It is a much different approach to javascript development. Once you get your head around it and figure out how to breakdown your code into discreet units of functionality it really is quite slick.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I appreciate it, but that's as confusing as the manual.  There's clearly some knowledge you've internalized that I'm not getting because I don't have your background.  Why does it make a different if require.js processes data-main to load it vs. just loading the file via normal browser means.  Is asyc loading it?  Or is there something more?  (I'm interested in this on an implementation level, not necessarily just a user-programmer )

Comment: See the expanded answer. Hopefully I've let out a little bit of the internalized knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

src will load "scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js" first. Then data-main attribute will execute "scripts/main.js".