# Modular js with Dart 'js' package

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, interop, dart-html

With the dart interop [js package](https://pub.dev/packages/js) I am struggling to find a way of using multiple js files (either with CommonJS or ES6 syntax). It appears that as soon as an *import* statement is used within an external js lib file, an error:

> NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null:
> 'dart.global.someJsMethod'

is thrown when calling any methods with the *@JS()* syntax. I have tried using webpack to generate a single js file, but the error remains.

Do I just accept this and manually merge into one js file to get rid of all import statements? Or am I missing some secret sauce in my dart references?

Comment: Do you have an example of a JS file that isn't working? Also have you tried using `require` rather than `import`? I can't find any documentation one way or the other, but maybe the js package only supports CommonJS. (`require` is CommonJS and `import` is ES6.)

Comment: It appears it is not possible. In the end I needed to use the require.js library see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027046/difference-between-data-main-and-normal-script-loading/35037150#35037150 for guidance.